# Erro no cálculo de data usando struct tm

Tags: c, datetime

Meu software fica incrementado a data em 5 minutos e funciona perfeitamente do modo que estou fazendo, entretando achei um bug que somente no dia 16/02 desse ano o cálculo não fica correto, segue exemplo:

```
16/1/119 23:55:0
16/1/119 23:55:0

16/1/119 23:60:0
16/1/119 23:0:0

16/1/119 23:5:0
16/1/119 23:5:0

16/1/119 23:10:0
16/1/119 23:10:0

16/1/119 23:15:0
16/1/119 23:15:0
```

Ao invés de passar para 00h do dia 17 ele volta para as 23 do dia 16, testei com outros dias e isso não acontece, estou usando a lib `time.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() 
{
    struct tm dt_stream;
    int i;

    dt_stream.tm_mday = 16;
    dt_stream.tm_mon = 1; //02 Fev;
    dt_stream.tm_year = 19 + 2000 - 1900; //2019
    dt_stream.tm_hour = 23;
    dt_stream.tm_min = 50;
    dt_stream.tm_sec = 0;


    for ( i=0; i<5; i++) {
        dt_stream.tm_min = dt_stream.tm_min + 5;

        printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d\n", dt_stream.tm_mday, dt_stream.tm_mon, dt_stream.tm_year, \
                               dt_stream.tm_hour,dt_stream.tm_min, dt_stream.tm_sec);


        mktime(&dt_stream);

        printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d\n", dt_stream.tm_mday, dt_stream.tm_mon, dt_stream.tm_year, \
                              dt_stream.tm_hour,dt_stream.tm_min, dt_stream.tm_sec);

        printf("*****\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do porque isso esta acontecendo?
Compilando com gcc, rodando no Linux.

```
tm_mon = 0-11
tm_year = year-1900
```

Comment: Provavelmente é o fim do horário de verão brasileiro: à meia-noite do dia 17, os relógios são atrasados em uma hora, de volta para 23h. Vc tentou continuar somando para ver se depois ele muda para o dia 17? Verifique o valor do campo `tm_isdst` também, pois ele indica se está ou não em horário de verão: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: Sim, se eu fizer o loop 15 vezes, por exemplo, ele chega novamente as 23h55 e passa para o dia 17 a 0h

Quanto ao ISDST fica assim 

16/1/119 23:55:0 ISDST 4196256
16/1/119 23:55:0 ISDST 1
*****
16/1/119 23:60:0 ISDST 1
16/1/119 23:0:0 ISDST 0

Comment: O programa deve estar usando o timezone configurado no Linux. Eu não lembro mto bem como configurar programaticamente o timezone utilizado, mas dá pra fazer via linha de comando. Se não quiser ter efeitos de horário de verão, dá pra fazer no bash algo como `TZ=UTC ./seuprograma`. Aí o programa passa a usar UTC (em vez do timezone do sistema operacional), e como UTC não tem horário de verão, não vai mais ocorrer esses casos.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente a causa é o [fim do horário de verão brasileiro](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2019): à meia-noite do dia 17/02/2019, os relógios são atrasados em uma hora, de volta para as 23h do dia 16. Ou seja, quando o relógio está em 23:59:59.999 (no horário de verão), em vez de mudar para meia-noite, ele muda para 23:00 (no horário "normal").

Por isso, todos os minutos entre 23:00 e 23:59 ocorrem **duas vezes**: uma no horário de verão, e outra no horário "normal". **Isso não é um *bug***, e sim o funcionamento normal. É estranho que um horário ocorra duas vezes no mesmo dia, mas é exatamente assim que funciona. Quando um horário ocorre duas vezes (uma no horário de verão e outra no horário "normal"), é chamado de [*overlap*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340388).

Para verificar isso, modifiquei o seu *loop* para continuar por mais algumas iterações. Também imprimi o valor do campo `tm_isdst`, que segundo a [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/), imprime um valor maior que zero quando está em horário de verão, e zero quando não está em horário de verão:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dt_stream.tm_min = dt_stream.tm_min + 5;

    mktime(&dt_stream);

    printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d - %d\n", dt_stream.tm_mday, dt_stream.tm_mon, dt_stream.tm_year, \
                          dt_stream.tm_hour,dt_stream.tm_min, dt_stream.tm_sec, dt_stream.tm_isdst);

    printf("*****\n");
}
```

O resultado:

```
16/1/119 23:55:0 - 1
*****
16/1/119 23:0:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:5:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:10:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:15:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:20:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:25:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:30:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:35:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:40:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:45:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:50:0 - 0
*****
16/1/119 23:55:0 - 0
*****
17/1/119 0:0:0 - 0
*****
17/1/119 0:5:0 - 0
*****
17/1/119 0:10:0 - 0
*****
17/1/119 0:15:0 - 0
*****
17/1/119 0:20:0 - 0
*****
17/1/119 0:25:0 - 0
*****
17/1/119 0:30:0 - 0
*****
```

Repare que na primeira linha, o valor de `tm_isdst` é 1, pois está em horário de verão. Na segunda linha em diante, o relógio foi atrasado de volta para 23h e não está mais em horário de verão (portanto, `tm_isdst` passa a ser 0).

Em seguida, continuando o *loop*, vemos que agora quando chega em 23:55, na próxima iteração ele muda para o dia 17.